# Using date filter in Aggregate , Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am currently learning mongodb queries. My collection Expenses is like::

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("59815d4704ca1760a45957ca"),
    "userEmail" : "lk@gmail.com",
    "expenseAmount" : -200,
    "expenseRemark" : "aa",
    "expenseCategory" : "billing",
    "transactionType" : "debit",
    "entryTime" : ISODate("2017-08-02T05:03:57Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59815d5404ca1760a45957cb"),
    "userEmail" : "lk@gmail.com",
    "expenseAmount" : -300,
    "expenseRemark" : "ff",
    "expenseCategory" : "transport",
    "transactionType" : "debit",
    "entryTime" : ISODate("2017-08-02T05:04:11Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5980191d04ca1760a45957cd"),
    "userEmail" : "lk@gmail.com",
    "expenseAmount" : -100,
    "expenseRemark" : "rr",
    "expenseCategory" : "billing",
    "transactionType" : "debit",
    "entryTime" : ISODate("2017-08-01T06:00:46Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5980192604ca1760a45957ce"),
    "userEmail" : "lk@gmail.com",
    "expenseAmount" : -200,
    "expenseRemark" : "qq",
    "expenseCategory" : "transport",
    "transactionType" : "debit",
    "entryTime" : ISODate("2017-08-01T06:01:03Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5980192e04ca1760a45957cf"),
    "userEmail" : "lk@gmail.com",
    "expenseAmount" : -470,
    "expenseRemark" : "ff",
    "expenseCategory" : "transport",
    "transactionType" : "debit",
    "entryTime" : ISODate("2017-08-01T06:01:11Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59816ac004ca1760a45957d0"),
    "userEmail" : "lk@gmail.com",
    "expenseAmount" : -500,
    "expenseRemark" : "raj",
    "expenseCategory" : "transport",
    "transactionType" : "debit",
    "entryTime" : ISODate("2017-08-02T06:01:26Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59816acb04ca1760a45957d1"),
    "userEmail" : "lk@gmail.com",
    "expenseAmount" : -100,
    "expenseRemark" : "pet",
    "expenseCategory" : "pets",
    "transactionType" : "debit",
    "entryTime" : ISODate("2017-08-02T06:01:37Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("597d7a9c04ca1760a45957d2"),
    "userEmail" : "lk@gmail.com",
    "expenseAmount" : -500,
    "expenseRemark" : "gt",
    "expenseCategory" : "sports",
    "transactionType" : "debit",
    "entryTime" : ISODate("2017-07-30T06:20:04Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("597d7aaa04ca1760a45957d3"),
    "userEmail" : "lk@gmail.com",
    "expenseAmount" : -560,
    "expenseRemark" : "mov",
    "expenseCategory" : "entertainment",
    "transactionType" : "debit",
    "entryTime" : ISODate("2017-07-30T06:20:14Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5983f28723485dd901791bc9"),
    "userEmail" : "lk@gmail.com",
    "expenseAmount" : 5560,
    "expenseRemark" : "income",
    "expenseCategory" : "entertainment",
    "transactionType" : "credit",
    "entryTime" : ISODate("2017-07-25T06:20:14Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I want a result where i can get the total of **expenseAmount**, which is between 2 dates **entryTime**.

I am trying

```
    db.expenses.aggregate(
  {$match:{"entryTime":{$gt: new ISODate("2017-07-01T00:00:00Z") , $lt: new ISODate("2017-07-31T00:00:00Z")}}},
  {
    $group:{,
      _id : {total : {$sum : "$expenseAmount"}}

    }
  }
)
```

I tried few different things, but could not get the result.
But this is not working. Can anyone please help me in getting the total of expenseAmount, between 2 dates.

EDIT-1

```
    db.expenses.aggregate(
  {$match:{"entryTime":{$gt: new ISODate("2017-07-01T00:00:00Z") , $lt: new ISODate("2017-07-31T00:00:00Z")}}},
  {"$group": {"_id": null, "total": { "$sum": "$expenseAmount"}}}
);
```

Comment: There does not appear to be anything wrong with the "range" itself, but the `$group` is incorrect. You actually mean `{ "$group": { "_id": null, "total": { "$sum": "$expenseAmount" } }` for the total here.

Comment: @NeilLunn, this also not working

Comment: Works for me. Explain what you mean by "not working". Because what you posted was a syntax error, and that's what I told you to correct. What I see is that the last three documents as posted in the question are selected and then a total is returned for the `"expenseAmount"` of all those three documents. I did miss a brace though, and I guess you did not pick up on that so `{ "$group": { "_id": null, "total": { "$sum": "$expenseAmount" } } }`

Comment: Please see my EDIT-1. It does not return anything, just blank in console.

Comment: Its working now. I am getting { "_id" : null, "total" : 4500 }

Comment: Well when you actually do what I told you then of course it works. You still likely have usage errors, but as a "full" correction: `db.expenses.aggregate([ { $match:{"entryTime":{$gt: new ISODate("2017-07-01T00:00:00Z") , $lt: new ISODate("2017-07-31T00:00:00Z")}}}, { $group:{ _id : null, total : {$sum : "$expenseAmount"}}} ])`. Note the wrapping "array" `[]` and the separation of arguments. Also simply `new Date("2017-07-01")` is sufficient.